# Cyclic Group Order of Elements

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

In "Mathematical Methods for Physics and Engineering" by Riley, Hobson, and Bence, in the chapter on group theory, the *order of the element* $X$ in the finite group $G$ is the number $m$ such that $X^m=I$; thus, the order of the identity is always $1$. A *cyclic group* is then defined as a group generated from a single element $X$, i.e.,
$$G=\{I,X,X^2,X^3,\dots,X^{g-1}\},$$
where $g$ is the order of the group. They then write that

> It is clear that cyclic groups are always Abelian and that each element, apart
> from the identity, has order g, the order of the group itself.

I don't see why the second statement is true; for example, when $g=4$, then the element $X^2$ should have order $2$. Am I wrong?

Update: I reached out to the first author and he said that this error was corrected in the $18$th reprint of the $3$rd edition (I was looking at the $2$nd edition).

Comment: It is not true, that's why you don't see why it  is true.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept an answer, @DavidRaveh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right.

---

The main problem is in the given definition of order. In fact, the order $|a|\in\Bbb N$ of an element $a$ in a group is the smallest positive integer such that $a^{|a|}=e$.

---

Consider the cyclic group $\Bbb Z_6$ of six elements. Let $X$ be a generator. Then $X^2$ has order three and $X^3$ has order two.

Comment: I think you should point out that the notion of ‘order’ given in the book is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, @Shinrin-Yoku. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

The definition for order is a bit weird in the book. Generally you would say that the order of $X \in G$ is the *least* integer for which $X^m = I$ (if such an integer exists). I believe what they meant to articulate is that if $G$ is cyclic of order $n$, then raising any element of the group to $n$ will give you the identity, which is *not* the same as saying an element has that order, if you're using the standard definition.

To see why it's the case, let $G = \langle X \rangle$ with $|G| = n$, then for any $Y \in G$ note that $Y = X^k$ for some $1 \leq k \leq n$ by definition of being a cyclic group, then
$$
Y^n = (X^k)^n = X^{kn} = (X^n)^k = 1^k = 1.
$$
This is what I imagine they mean.

**Edit:** I base this off the sentence

> the order of the element $X$ in the finite group $G$ is the number $m$ such that $X^m =I$

in your answer. It doesn't make sense to say *the* number $m$ such that $X^m =I$ since it certainly isn't unique, that's why the definition of order usually specifies minimal.